# I want to let others use my functions like registration password validation, email validation etc.. in php

Tags: php, include

I'm a php developer, whenever i'm creating a websites that contains a login/rgistration functionality, simply using few php functions and jquery ajax validation codes by including it to the working site. Now i have copied those reusing functions into a file and kept into my website somewhere, i have tried to access it but some error popped out as

> "Warning: include() [function.include]: http:// wrapper is disabled in
>   the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\88db\vsm\admin\includes\functions.php"

and

> "Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'http://desireit.in/codes/includes/resize.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\88db\vsm\admin\includes\functions.php on line 9"

desireit.in is my website where i have kept the resize.php file which contains my reusable functions.

Please give me some advice regarding this problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the access / error logs? You'll likely find what you need to know there.

Comment: Enable [`allow_url_include`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include)

Comment: Can't we make our php code available for others like <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> jquery code ?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the path to the file you want to include, not the http:// location.
 so your includes string could be something like:

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/functions.php"); ?>
```

Where the path is adjusted to the correction location for your server files.

Be aware that $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is not always set in some servers and may deliver unexpected results in others. Best to test before depending upon it.

If you do not get the expected results from the above, you can do this instead:

```
<?php include dirname(__FILE__) . '/your_path_to_the_include_file/includes.php';?>
```

Again, where the path is adjusted to the correction location for your server files.

You do have the option of enabling the ability to call include files with http:// in your PHP .ini file, but it creates security risks and delivers no real value as compared to the above solutions.